# Eager load at BaseModel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently in a model I do the following to automatically eager load all relationships:

```
public static $eagerLoad = ['country', 'product', 'membership.package'];

public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    $query = parent::newQuery(true);
    return $query->with(static::$eagerLoad);
}
```

How could I transport this to the BaseModel?

When I try it returns `eloquent call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object`

**Update:**

In my BaseModel I have like this:

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    if(property_exists(get_class($this), 'eagerLoad'))
    {                       
        $query = parent::newQuery(true);
        return $query->with($this::$eagerLoad);
    }
}
```

It returns `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\firebolt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 713 and defined`

If I leave empty or return false, it throws `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use that (the way you are doing it now for eager loading automatically) because all you need to do is only add a `protected $with` property in your model for example:

```
protected $with = ['country', 'product', 'membership.package'];
```

Now your model will automatically eager load the related model provided in `$with`. So if you do something like this:

```
$model = Model::find(1);
```

All the related models will be also eager loaded with this `$model` object.

Comment: Is this available in 4.1?

Comment: Yes, it's available :-)

Comment: This is super cool Mr. WereWolf, thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: In `v-3` it was `$includes` instead of `$with` and you are welcome :-)